# Passing a MATLAB object as an input parameter on Java

Tags: java, swing, matlab, parameter-passing, jtextfield

I have a GUI on MATLAB with an edit uicontrol. I’ve made a Java jar library that I'm using on my code. I want to pass this uicontrol as an input parameter to a constructor on Java.
The reason is because I like change the result of the String property inside Java.

This pseudocode could be an example:

MATLAB

```
javaaddpath('myjar.jar'); % Adding Java library
import <packagename>.*; % Route
server = ConstructorName( handles.<myUiControl> ); % IS HERE WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT
```

Java

```
ConstructorName(JTextField jTF) {
jTF.setText("whatever");
```

}

Is it possible? Maybe is unsupported that I want to do... In this page tells about it is possible as a Java Object, but not in the chase of MATLAB object:
http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html

But I've seen I could use 'findobj' to wrap uicontrols:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects

I'm not sure if it's valid only on MATLAB environment...
Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have little experience with this, but `findjobj` should give you access to the underlying Java-peer handle of the "Edit uicontrol".

The following worked for me:

```
>> figure('Menubar','none', 'Position',[400 400 250 100]);
>> h = uicontrol('Style','edit', 'Position',[30 40 200 25], 'String','')
h =
    0.0101

>> drawnow; pause(0.1);
>> jh = findjobj(h, 'nomenu')
jh =
    javahandle_withcallbacks.com.mathworks.hg.peer.EditTextPeer$hgTextField


>> jedit = java(handle(jh))
jedit =
com.mathworks.hg.peer.EditTextPeer$hgTextField[...TRUNCATED STUFF...]
```

This is an object of class: `com.mathworks.hg.peer.EditTextPeer$hgTextField`. This derives from `com.mathworks.mwswing.MJTextField` which itself extends the standard `javax.swing.JTextField`.

Next we pass the object reference to the Java code. I had to write the constructor as accepting an `Object` and cast that as `JTextField`:

```
>> javaaddpath('C:\path\to\my\java\classes')

>> c = MyClass(jedit)
c =
MyClass@483e74d7

>> c.setString('hello world!')
```

[image: edit_uicontrol]

#### MyClass.java

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class MyClass {
    private JTextField jtf = null;
    public MyClass(Object obj) {
        jtf = (JTextField) obj;
    }
    public void setString(String str) {
        jtf.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Of course this is all undocumented and completely unsupported by MathWorks..

Comment: You are a genius! I was thinking about passing an Object and so on, but actually the key line code is:java(handle(jh)).

Comment: By the way, it (setText()) also works on the Android side. I'm really thankful!

Comment: thanks :) You can actually see this code used internally by MATLAB in `edit javaGetHandles.m` to get the Java handles